# how to run jar file on RHEL5?

Tags: java, jar, rhel5

I have made a jar file which i tested in windows and it works fine. now i want to test it for red hat enterprise linux 5. but i dont know how to run jar files in rhel5.

i've tried `java -jar My.jar` but it says `bash: java: command not found`. i've set `JAVA_HOME` variable as `export JAVA_HOME=/root/jdk1.6.0_21` but still not working.

can anybody tell me how to run jar file in rhel5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `PATH` variable , something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

replace `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin` with path to your `jdk's bin` directory.

The problem is your terminal tries to find `java` command from the `PATH` , but it couldn't find it.

**Update:**

> You need to setup global config in /etc/profile OR /etc/bash.bashrc file for all users:

```
# vi /etc/profile
```

Next setup PATH / JAVA_PATH variables as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

Comment: yes you are right i get it worked but if i wanna run my jar by double clicking on it? what to do for it? is it possible in rhel5?

Comment: I haven't used rhel but in ubuntu i right click in jar and set `open with ` jdk and in permission `allow this program to execute` I check it. check similar things for rhel

Comment: i'm able to give permission to execute but cant find jdk in open with dialog. If i browse through `java folder` what should i select i try selecting `jar`, `java`, `javaws` but niether works. what should i do?

Comment: is there anything like custom command in open with, if so then supply `java -jar`

Answer (score 0):

Top tip but slightly off topic.

1) Install your JDK in `/usr/local/jdkX.X.X_XX/`
2) Create a symbolic link `/usr/local/java` -> your chosen JDK installation

When you install new versions of java or if you want to revert to an older version, just change the symbolic link.